# Python3 Socket Programming with Client & Server on 127.0.0.1 works - on different Nodes in LAN does not work- why?

Tags: python, sockets

I have just done some https://realpython.com/python-sockets/ socket communication exercises which are all related to local host (127.0.0.1, Port 65432 ) communication only. Well understood - works fine.

But -  communication between different IPs in a common LAN (no firewall inbetween) does not work (e.g. between 172.24.3.1 and 127.24.3.2.)

I get the error message

`ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

on client side.

All nodes are ssh enabled - I strongly assume I need ssh-key authorization included when establishing the socket connection between different nodes - am I right? Or any other reason?

I haven't found any hint, in which way I need to extend my code  (eventually ssh- key authorization ?)  to let my socket communication run between different nodes.

Can you please give me a hint, where is my thought mistake, resp. where to read principles / details?

I wonder why my different node socket communication prior implemented in C-language years ago is still running between the same nodes above works pretty fine - without any security considerations in the code?

Troubled!

Thanx & BR

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - stupid - I was mistaken ... the magic is in this command sequence:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

# ...

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

I need to define HOST = '' instead to allow all IP adresses (other than localhost only) to connect.

But this raises my next question:

If I do only want to allow IP-nodes to connect via ssh encryption only, how do I add this security level at socket programming level, please?

Thanx & BR

Comment: *"... how do I  ..."* - Don't do a follow-up _question_ in your _answer_. This is not a discussion forum. Ask a new question instead with sufficient context.